# Plotting more than 2 Features for Decision Tree Classifier using matplotlib python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

### The Dataset

I've been playing around the [Pima Indians Dataset](https://github.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/blob/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv) on Classifying using Decision Tree Classifier. However I've got my results and as obvious stage I've been looking for Visualization of same.

here's the head of the dataset:

```
   TimesPregnant  GlucoseConcentration  BloodPrs  SkinThickness  Serum   BMI  \
0              6                   148        72             35      0  33.6   
1              1                    85        66             29      0  26.6   
2              8                   183        64              0      0  23.3   
3              1                    89        66             23     94  28.1   
4              0                   137        40             35    168  43.1   

   DiabetesFunct  Age  Class  
0          0.627   50      1  
1          0.351   31      0  
2          0.672   32      1  
3          0.167   21      0  
4          2.288   33      1
```

### Plotting more than 2 features?

Here's the code I've assembled using references and tutorials around web. Apparently it doesn't work for more than 2 features. In here, as you can notice except the last column, all the others are my features.

### The code

```
# Visualising the Training set results
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Decision Tree (Train set)')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Estimated Salary')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

You may notice those `X1`, `X2` making up from meshgrid so as to utilize the space I'm using for coloring, however you are free to ignore if solution you propose covers plotting more than 2 features as far as it is on matplotlib.

Now, I can't make 8 X's for 8 Features here, I look for quite efficient way to do same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
from itertools import product
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sts

features = [np.linspace(0, 5),

            np.linspace(9, 14),

            np.linspace(6, 11),
            np.linspace(3, 8)]

labels = ['height',
          'weight',
          'bmi',
          'age']

n = len(features)
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(n, n, figsize=(4*n, 4*n))
fig.subplots_adjust(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)

for (x,y),ax in zip(product(features, features), axarr.T.flat):
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    # get some fake data for demo purposes
    mnorm = sts.multivariate_normal([x.mean()**(7/10), y.mean()**(11/10)])
    Z = mnorm.pdf(np.stack([X, Y], 2))

    ax.contourf(X, Y, Z)

# label and style the plot
# ...in progress
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That's cool, however where can I put my line of ML Model `classifier.predict`?

Comment: Also, I've seen similar plots with seaborn. It's it possible to do with seaborn as well?

Comment: If you could respond for classifier, that would be great. I'm unable to figure out where to put my classifier here.